# How to search for files in OneDrive using MSGraph query API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, graph-explorer

Using Graph Explorer I can list files in the "Brendan" directory of my oneDrive.
eg The API call below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children
```

correctly lists 2 files as
`"name": "bren1.txt"`, and  `"name": "test.pdf"`,

However if I try to use the query API using this API
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children/query
with this body

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "bren"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I get

```
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-04-25T06:03:59",
            "request-id": "e3c688e1-dc08-4302-acdb-1b133a83bae3",
            "client-request-id": "fc6fc88d-38ee-451b-3ada-1914d2f96e91"
        }
    }
}
```

There are no concrete examples I can find on how to use the MSGraph query API to search for files in directories (driveItems) on OneDrive. **Where am I going wrong?**

Also `?$filter` also seems to work very sporadically, for example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children?$filter=startswith(name,'bren')
```

correctly returns `"name": "bren1.txt"`

but     `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children?$filter=endswith(name,'txt')` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children?$filter=contains(name,'bren')` both return

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-04-25T06:13:56",
            "request-id": "28cee436-ec08-4107-8947-380b387ada7d",
            "client-request-id": "6d754b02-aaef-7360-b3ca-c0341a9b6f19"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children?$search="name:bren1.txt"` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/children?$search="bren1.txt"`

both of which ignore the search parameter and return everything.

Again **Where am I going wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using `search(q='{search-text}')` for searching files.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Brendan:/search(q='bren1.txt')
```

The query above will search for items in the "Brendan" directory of your OneDrive. It searches the value across filename, metadata, and file content.

I think that `$filter` query is ignored.

Second option is using `/search/query` endpoint

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "filename:bren1.txt AND path:\"https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx/Documents/Brendan\""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can filter items by file name and scope the query to a particular folder within a OneDrive or site.

Documentation:

[Search for files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Filter in search queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries)

Comment: Ok Thank you, my mistake with search(q='{search-text}') was searching /Brendan/children instead of /Brendan. My mistake with the  /search/query endpoint was putting the path in in the URL instead of the body as you have shown. Thanks for prompt reply.